# How to branch off of an rxjs stream conditionally?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I am trying to simulate the "brush" feature like the one in any image editor.

I have the following streams:

- `$pointerDown`: pointer pressed down
- `$pointerUp`: pointer pressed up
- `$position`: position of the brush
- `$escape`: Escape key pressed

### What I want to do

When the user is dragging the mouse, do temporary calculations. If the mouse is up, then commit those changes. If the escape key is pressed then do not commit those changes.

What I am currently handling is the first case:

```
$pointerDown.pipe(
   r.switchMap(() =>
       $position.pipe(
           r.throttleTime(150),
           r.map(getNodesUnderBrush),
           r.tap(prepareChanges),
           r.takeUntil($pointerUp),
           r.finalize(commitBrushStroke))
)).subscribe()
```

How can I end the stream in two different ways? What is the idiomatic rxjs for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question I can see you need to have some kind of `state` over time. Here your `state` is the `pointerdown/move/dragging` observable, that needs to be `accumulated` or `cleared` and finally `emitted`. When I see such a `state` scenario I always like to use the [scan](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) operator:

**Pre**

*For the sake of simple example i did not use your predefined observables. If you have issues adapting your specific pointer usecase to this very similar one, I can try to update it so it is closer to your question*

**1. What could represent my state**

*Here I am using an enum [status] to later on react on the event that happened before and an accumulation [acc] for the points over time*

```
interface State {
  acc: number[],
  status: Status
}

enum Status {
  init,
  move,
  finish,
  escape
}

const DEFAULT_STATE: State = {
  acc: [],
  status: Status.init
}
```

**2. Write functions that mutate the state**

*Your requirement can be split into: accumulate [pointerdown$ + position$], finish [pointerup$], escape [escape$]*

```
const accumulate = (index: number) => (state: State): State =>
({status: Status.move, acc: [...state.acc, index]});

const finish = () => (state: State): State =>
({status: Status.finish, acc: state.acc})

const escape = () => (state: State): State =>
({status: Status.escape, acc: []})
```

**3. Map your functions to your observables**

```
merge(
  move$.pipe(map(accumulate)),
  finish$.pipe(map(finish)),
  escape$.pipe(map(escape))
)
```

**4. Use the functions in the scan where your state over time is placed**

```
scan((acc: State, fn: (state: State) => State) => fn(acc), DEFAULT_STATE)
```

**5. Process your mutated state**

*Here we only want to process if we have a finish, so we filter for it*

```
filter(state => state.status === Status.finish),
```

**Inner state sample**

1. move$.next('1') = State: {status: move, acc: ['1']}
2. escape$.next() = State: {status: escape, acc: []}
3. move$.next('2') = State: {status: move, acc: ['2']}
4. finish$.next() = State: {status: finish, acc: ['2']}

Running [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-move-finish-escape-buffer)

*FYI: It is pretty hard to get this mindset of solving state problems with rxjs. But once you understand the flow behind the idea, you can use it in nearly every statefull scenario. You will avoid sideeffects, stick to rxjs workflow and you can easily optimize/debugg your code.*

Comment: I remember seeing an approach very similar to this in a video before. I like this approach. I was hoping though that there is some "first-class" operator that deals with branching off of streams. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you search for some "switch" from one observable to another you might can use iif. Otherwise why not writing your own custom operator :) You can use the answer above and wrap it into an operator. Your requirements are just a bit special, so if you need this behavior more than 1 time. Wrap it :)

Comment: FYI: The solution I provided here can be adapted for every statefull rxjs scenario. An operator won't.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, when the user presses the **escape key** than the entire stream should be unsubscribed so that, when the users starts again the dragging with the **pointer mouse** down, the stream starts again emitting.

If this is the case, you may want to try `switchMap` with `$escape` and `merge`, in other words something like this

```
const drag$ = $pointerDown.pipe(
   r.switchMap(() =>
       $position.pipe(
           r.throttleTime(150),
           r.map(getNodesUnderBrush),
           r.tap(prepareChanges),
           r.takeUntil($pointerUp),
           r.finalize(commitBrushStroke))
))
const brush$ = $escape.pipe(
   startWith({}),  // emit any value at start just to allow the stream to start
   switchMap(() => drag$)
);
const stopBrush$ = $escape.pipe(tap(() => // do stuff to cancel));
merge(brush$, stopBrush$).subscribe();
```

The whole idea is that, any time `$escape` emits, the previous subscription to `drag$` is unsubscribed and a new one starts. At the same time any logic to cancel what needs to be cancelled can be performed.

I can not test this thing, so I hope I have not forgot something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Picci. How can I add custom processing for escape key? Because the `prepareChanges` that I am calling add some temporary fields to my dataset that I would need to clean in case the user presses the `escape` key to cancel. Also I think the unsubscription would still cause `r.finalize(commitBrushStroke)` to run since it would run on `complete`, `error` and `unsubscribe`.

Comment: I was hoping to find some kind of operator that would work something like this: `take until the one of these two notifiers emits something, and continue with a given stream`

Comment: I have updated my response with something that could potentially work for your case. Just a note on `finalize`. According to my understanding `finalize` gets fired with the source observable completes or errors, not when it is unsubscribed. If you want to have logic fired at unsubscribe time you need to create your own Observable via its constructor and return a `TeardownLogic` from the function you pass to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting problem!

Here's my approach:

```js
const down$ = fromEvent(div, 'mousedown');
const up$ = fromEvent(div, 'mouseup');
const calc$ = of('calculations');
const esc$ = fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
  .pipe(
    filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.code === 'Escape')
  );

down$ // The source of the stream - mousedown events
  .pipe(
    switchMapTo(calc$.pipe( // Do some calculations
      switchMapTo(
        merge( // `merge()` - want to stop making the calculations when either `up$` or `esc$` emit
          up$.pipe(mapTo({ shouldCommit: true })),
          esc$.pipe(mapTo({ shouldCommit: false })),
        ).pipe(first()) // `first()` - either of these 2 can stop the calculations;
      )
    ))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-brush-editor?file=index.ts).

Comment: I like your approach. I think what you did in `merge(...).pipe(first())` is similar to a `race(...)`. I am going to test this.

Comment: `merge().pipe(first())` differs from `race()`! [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/merge-first-vs-race?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's pretty simple way to do that with `toArray()` and `takeUntil()`. I'm assuming that when you said you want "commit" changes you want to collect all changes and process them all at once. Otherwise, the same approach would work with `buffer()` as well.

```
$pointerDown.pipe(
   switchMap(() => $position.pipe(
     throttleTime(150),
     map(getNodesUnderBrush),
     tap(prepareChanges), // ?
     takeUntil($pointerUp),
     toArray(),
     takeUntil($escape),
  )
).subscribe(changes => {
  ...
  commitBrushStroke(changes);
})
```

So the entire trick is whether you complete the inner chain before or after `toArray`. When you complete it before `toArray()` then `toArray()` will emits a single array of all changes it has collected so far. If you complete it after `toArray()` then the chain is disposed and `toArray()` will discard everything and just unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes an other possible solution very much like your original:

```
    const start$ = fromEvent(document, "mousedown").pipe(
      tap((event: MouseEvent) => this.start = `x: ${event.clientX}, y: ${event.clientY}`)
    );
    const drag$ = fromEvent(document, "mousemove").pipe(
      tap((event: MouseEvent) => (this.move = `x: ${event.clientX}, y: ${event.clientY}`)      )
    );
    const stop$ = fromEvent(document, "mouseup").pipe(
      tap((event: MouseEvent) => (this.stop = `x: ${event.clientX}, y: ${event.clientY}`))
    );
    const cancel$ = fromEvent(document, "keydown").pipe(
      filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.code === "Escape"),
      tap(() => this.stop = 'CANCELLED')
    );

    const source$ = start$
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() =>
          drag$.pipe(
            takeUntil(merge(stop$, cancel$))
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe();
```

The stream can end in two ways merging both takeUntil conditions:

```
takeUntil(merge(stop$, cancel$))
```

Here is the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gw7gyr